# The method 'then' isn't defined for the type 'User' flutter firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am working on app where some users have admin role and others have user roles. The class below checks the assigned roles to users and direct them to the appropriate screen. The issue is I keep getting this error **The method 'then' isn't defined for the type 'User'.** I have gone through a few documents posted on this platform and I have increased the version of my packages in pubspec.yaml to make sure all is updated but the problem still persists. Any help is welcome

```
 class UserManagement {
  Widget handleAuth() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          print(snapshot.data.uid);
          return AdminDashboard();
        }
        return LoginScreen();
      },
    );
  }

  final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  authorizeAdmin(BuildContext context) {
    auth.then((user) {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .where('uid', isEqualTo: user.uid)
          .get()
          .then((docs) {
        if (docs.docs[0].exists) {
          if (docs.docs[0].data()['role'] == 'admin') {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AdminDashboard()),
            );
          } else {
            print('Access Denied');
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the .then statement. Fetching the `User` is [synchronous](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth/changelog#0180) with the new version of firebase so you just have to get the user from the `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;` and use it in your method. For example in your method it would look like:

```
final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  authorizeAdmin(BuildContext context) {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .where('uid', isEqualTo: user.uid)
          .get()
          .then((docs) {
        if (docs.docs[0].exists) {
          if (docs.docs[0].data()['role'] == 'admin') {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AdminDashboard()),
            );
          } else {
            print('Access Denied');
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }
```